# How to query for objects with a certain property in a Firestore collection, Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query for objects in firestore collection with a certain property, my Firestore DB looks as shown in the below picture.

The below code does not work as I am interested in querying for objects based on the the property inside an object. In this case I want all the cases (objects) with `"status"=="treated"` Is there a way to do it ?

```
  const db = firebase.firestore();

  const casesRef = db.collection("mgm/hospital/cases");

  // Create a query against the collection.
  var query = casesRef.where("status", "==", "active").limit(25);
  const queryRef = query.get();

  queryRef.then(function(documentSnapshots) {
    const cases = documentSnapshots.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
    console.log(cases);
  });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the field `patientDetails` is a map, the following should do the trick:

```
var query = casesRef.where("patientDetails.status", "==", "active").limit(25);
```

Comment: I am unable keep firebase user signed in after page refresh in React JS, I've posted a question here, what could I be doing wrong ? could you please advice stackoverflow.com/q/64024613/2534233